# Слово "точно" в начале предложения

Tags: выбор-слов, значение-слов

Что означает слово "точно", употребленное в начале предложения?

**Точно крысы, воровки.**

Comment: А можно продолжение привести? Трактовка зависит от того, к чему отнесено слово, к глаголу (ведут себя словно крысы) или к существительному (это точно крысы).

Answer (score 2):

[**ТОЧНО**](https://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/1056354/%D0%A2%D0%9E%D0%A7%D0%9D%D0%9E)
**1.** *Нареч.* к точный во 2 и 3 знач. Точно определить что-нибудь. Точно исполнить поручение. Точно переписать что-нибудь.
*Она всё делала точно и ловко* (Федин).
**2.** В соединении со словами “такой”, “так” и (реже) “тот” употр. в знач. *совершенно, вполне.* Точно такая же книга.
*Невежи судят точно так* (Крылов).
**3.** ***Частица утвердительная***. В начале ответа употребляется в значении **да, так, совершенно верно** (устар.).
*Точно, я хорошо обставлен, и дела мои недурны* (Гончаров).
**4.** *Вводное слово.* Действительно, в самом деле (устар.).
Сапоги, точно, были хорошо сшиты (Гоголь).
**5.** ***Союз сравнительный.*** **Как, словно, будто**.
*Кричит, точно помешанный. Точно с цепи сорвался.*

Я вижу здесь два варианта.
"Точно", как утвердительная частица, тогда пунктуация будет такая (с запятой):

**— Это и впрямь были крысы?

— Точно** [да, совершенно верно], **крысы, воровки.**

Как сравнительный союз:

**— А как они себя вели?

— Точно** [будто, как] **крысы, воровки.**

Answer (score 0):

В зaвисимости от контекста слова "точно крысы" могут обозначать уверенность в том, что это крысы, или сравнение с крысами.